# Communication error between two nodes on two distributed machines

Tags: ros, virtualbox, multiplemachines

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I estabilshed a network enviromnent between two machines. The first machine is a local host and the second machine is a Virtual Machine (VM). I've tested the network configuration and all worked fine. I have a bi-directional connectivity between the two machines.

- The local host has a static IP: **`192.168.56.1`** (name is **lap64**)
- The virtual machine has a IP of: **`192.1168.56.101`** (name is **vm_vbox**)
- And I set the ROS_MASTER_URI to **'192.168.56.1'**.

According to this, I build up a simple Publisher and Subscriber Node in C++ to transmit data between the network. First of all, I tested the Publisher and Subscriber on the local machine and it workd fine.

Next, I tried to transmit data from the Publisher (*talker*) running on the local machine to the Subscriber (*listener*) running on the Virtual machine. By typing rostopic on both sides, I can see each others nodes and topics.

But, by transmitting data I get and communication error in each node.
Here some more informations:

**Local host (running on electric)**

```
userA@lap64:~/ros_workspace/topic_tutorial$ rosnode info /listener
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Node [/listener]
Publications: 
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]

Subscriptions: 
 * /chatter [std_msgs/String]

Services: 
 * /listener/get_loggers
 * /listener/set_logger_level


contacting node http://vm_vbox:43126/ ...
ERROR: Communication with node[http://vm_vbox:43126/] failed!
```

**Virtual machine (running on fuerte)**

```
userB@vm_vbox:~/ros_workspace$ rosnode info /talker
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Node [/talker]
Publications: 
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]
 * /chatter [std_msgs/String]

Subscriptions: None

Services: 
 * /talker/set_logger_level
 * /talker/get_loggers


contacting node http://lap64:52729/ ...
ERROR: Communication with node[http://lap64:52729/] failed!
```

*What could I have missed or configured wrong?*

Best regards from Germany.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34064/communication-error-between-two-nodes-on-two-distributed-machines/) by [GermanUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/2107/germanuser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2012-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, I'm not sure it's a good idea to try and communicate between two different versions of ROS. That could lead to some problems.

Second, have you configured the network properly? Try taking a look [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines). The general idea is that you choose a PC to be your "master". On this machine, before starting roscore or a roslaunch, you must perform (where MASTER_IP is the IP address of your "master" computer):

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://MASTER_IP:11311
export ROS_IP=MASTER_IP
```

On your second machine, you perform the following (where SLAVE_IP is the IP address of the second machine):

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://MASTER_IP:11311
export ROS_IP=SLAVE_IP
```

You must do this in every terminal that you use.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GermanUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/2107/germanuser/) on 2012-05-18**:
Now it does work!